# How to make concurrent HTTP requests with basic authentication

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, httr

My goal is to import a client's history of orders from Shopify. Shopify only allows me to import 250 orders per request, but my client has thousands.

Here's (basically) my current working solution using [httr](https://github.com/r-lib/httr) which is very slow

```
fetchedList <- list()

# Loop through pages of orders and collect them
for(pg in 1:10){

  requestURL <- paste0("https://abc-store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=", p)

  fetched <- httr::GET(
    url = requestURL,
    httr::add_headers(Accept = "application/json"),
    httr::authenticate(user = "foo", password = "bar")
  )

  # Append the fetched response to fetchedList 
  fetchedList <- c(fetchedList, list(fetched))
}

# Process the results...
```

I would like to speed this up by making multiple concurrent requests. How can I achieve this? It seems [curl](https://github.com/jeroen/curl) and [RCurl](https://github.com/omegahat/RCurl) both have support for this but I'm fairly new to HTTP and couldn't get either solution working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the multi api to do concurrent requests. See the manual page for `?multi_run` or the section about [async requests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#async_requests) in the vignette.

There are also packages that wrap the multi api to try and make it easier. The [crul package](https://github.com/ropensci/crul#asynchronous-requests) (note crul is not a typo :) or more if you want to get real fancy the [async](https://github.com/r-lib/async) package.

Comment: +1. This feature actually doesn't exist in crul yet but [it's coming](https://github.com/ropensci/crul/issues/70#issuecomment-379423495) (soon hopefully).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Jeroen who pointed me to the [crul](https://github.com/ropensci/crul) package. At the time, crul actually didn't have this functionality set up, but I spoke to the maintainer and he implemented it. So, as of v 0.5.2.9100 I can do

```
dd <- Async$new(urls = c(
  'https://abc-store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=1',
  'https://abc-store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=2',
  'https://abc-store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=3'
))
res <- dd$get(auth = auth(user = "foo", pwd = "bar"))
vapply(res, function(z) z$status_code, double(1))
vapply(res, function(z) z$success(), logical(1))
lapply(res, function(z) z$parse("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Terrific question. The vignettes in the `crul` package are essentially perfect too.